# Python processing multiple items in queue using workers

Tags: python

Im trying to build a simple multiprocessing application using queue.

Im starting 4 processes to process data from multiple website. I want each process to process different website but for some reason the processes runs multiple times and never exits.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import Queue
import requests

def readdata(item):
    print item
    r = requests.get(item)
    print 'read data'
    print r.status_code


def worker(queue):
   while True:
       try:
           print 'start process'
           item = queue.get()
           readdata(item)
           q.task_done()
       except:
           print "the end"
           break

if __name__ == "__main__":
     nthreads = 4
     queue = Queue.Queue()
     # put stuff in the queue here 
     moreStuff = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.cnn.com']
     for stuff in moreStuff:
         queue.put(stuff)
     procs = [Process(target = worker, args = (queue,)) for i in xrange(nthreads)]
     for p in procs:
       p.start()
     for p in procs:
       p.join()
```

Output:

```
    start process
http://www.google.com
start process
http://www.google.com
start process
http://www.google.com
start process
http://www.google.com
read data
200
start process
http://www.yahoo.com
read data
200
start process
http://www.yahoo.com
read data
200
start process
http://www.yahoo.com
read data
200
start process
http://www.yahoo.com
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
read data
200
start process
http://www.cnn.com
read data
200
start process
http://www.cnn.com
read data
200
start process
http://www.cnn.com
read data
200
start process
read data
200
start process
http://www.cnn.com
read data
200
start process
read data
200
start process
read data
200
start process
```

How do I check if the queue is empty and exit?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.empty()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty) for the `queue`

Also, as a suggestion, since your queue doesn't change, I'd do this instead:

```
while not queue.empty():  # Wait for the queue to finish
    pass

print('Queue finished')
```

instead of the:

```
for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

Or even better use [`JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue) instead:

```
for p in procs:
    p.start()
queue.join()
```

Comment: Thanks.I'm checking queue.empty() and break the loop and it works fine..but Im not sure why the same item is being processed multiple times.

Comment: Since the queue doesn't change, you could also use a `Pool` and simplify the whole thing, couldn't you?